# What is a simpler, more pythonic way of expressing the following?

Tags: python

```
return not a and not b
```

^ how do I express this in a better format

Comment: Maybe parens? `return (not a and not b)` Or DeMorgan's? `return not (a or b)`

Comment: Looks fine to me.  No reason to overcomplicate it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), perhaps?

```
return not (a or b)
```

I think it's sufficiently simple at that point

Comment: meh i think it was fine initially and possibly more clear to some ... (I know they are equivelent) ... (+1 all the same)

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks `not a and not b` is much better human-readable than `not (a or b)`?